# Wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1+) Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am getting this error on my barely-customized `devise` new password page:

`wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1+)`

My ERB is fairly simple:

```
<h1 style="color: black">Forgot Your Password?</h1>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path, html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>  <<<<<<<ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs text-left">
        <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Send Me Reset Password Instructions", class: "btn-custom" %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

But I can't seem to figure out why this error is being generated.  Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Have you tried running a debugging over that line, perhaps with Pry?

Comment: @iain, I'm not quite sure how to do that in this context....

Comment: This may help, there's a good section on debugging in Rails. Set your binding and then **n**ext **n**ext **n**ext until you reach the point it fails and you can start to laser in on the problem. https://www.sitepoint.com/pry-friends-rails/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `password_path` for `password_path(resource_name)`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!